# Do you apply data normalization to the data set you are trying to predict?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

Once you have trained a multi class classifier/model by normalizing the data of your selected features, do you also perform data normalization on the data of the selected features that you are using to predict their classes?

For example, if i have performed normalization on X_train and X_validation data sets, do i also need to perform data normalization on X_to_be_Classified dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely yes! You have to take care to use the exact same normalization parameters you used for your training data.

So let's assume that you are scaling your data to have zero mean and unit variance like `(X - mean(X)) / std(X)`, the you should use each feature's `std` and `mean` based on the training set, not based on the 'to be classified` set. Otherwise, model performance may worsen since the features are not exactly what the trained model is expecting.

Comment: Thank you, that was my initial hunch just wanted to verify.  I appreciate all of your help.